# How to add and show a Bootstrap tooltip inside a jQuery click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am trying to add and display a Bootstrap 3 tooltip from within a click function in jQuery.

It works well when I'm using an anonymous function for the click handler, but if I try to place the code into a named function I get the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$button.tooltip(...`

The contents of the JS file is below. This is loaded after both jQuery and bootstrap.min.js.

```
$(function() {
    function confirmClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $button = event.target;
        console.log($button);

        $button.tooltip({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            trigger: 'manual',
        }).tooltip('show');

        $button.unbind('click');
    }

    $('.btn-confirm').click(confirmClick);
})
```

Ultimately, I'm looking to use setTimeout to re-add the click handler and hide the tooltip after X seconds.

The end behavior will be the user clicking on the button, a tooltip appearing asking "Are you sure?" and if they click again before X seconds the link is followed. If not, the tooltip is hidden and the same action is prepared for the next click.

I've also tried adding the tooltip using wither a manual or click trigger and then manipulating it from within the confirmClick() function, but any attempt to hit .tooltip from within a named click function seems to fail.

Comment: Try `$button = $(event.target);`

Comment: @D4V1D That was it! Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your target with jQuery selector to use `.tooltip()`.

Do `$button = $(event.target);` instead of `$button = event.target;`.

Prepend your variable with `$` if, and only if, your variable stores a `jQuery` object.

Comment: Thank you! I had forgotten that event.target is the bare element.